# ElasticSearch Sorting on localized fields

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, localized

We are using ElasticSearch for storing the user profile data  and one of the field is roleId. There are more than 100 roles are possible in application and a user can have multiple roles and every role has localized texts for different different languages.

We have an web application which access the user profile form elastic search and there user role needs to be displayed in localized text for example if client locale[browser] is french then corresponding french localized text for roleId[ Assuming 101 is the role Id for the Manager] needs to be displayed.

Now the problem is
1. How to store the localized text for such kind of scenario. If we store it with original document then probably we are repeating the text too many and consuming too many space. 
2. We need sorting on the localized field.Is there any way to sort on localized field.

Please consider above scenario for providing any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried to store the localized text to see how it behaves for both your cases 1 and 2? It's not a problem for ES to index them.

Comment: Yes. we can do it but storing the localized values for every role  and for every language (we have approximately 25 languages) is not a good option. It will take unnecessary space and in my case data is growing. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: People are often too worried of storing too much data in ES, you should definitely not be afraid of denormalizing your data. Maybe instead of storing text you could store an `role_order` for each locale and then sort your documents according to that small integer.

Comment: But how are we going to define the ordering for roles. If today I define some ordering and tomorrow a new role added then how it will be managed. and ordering means If i have 100 roles and 25 languages then I have to maintain the ordering somewhere for 100 items  and order data size will be 25.  Maintaining that data will be quite difficult .

Comment: Again, if I were you I would try to index my document with the localized roles and see how it behaves. As the common saying goes: "Premature optimization is root of all evil" ;-)